Google Cloud - issues provisioning cloud shell machine
I am seeing this error today, after approximatley 20 minutes the first  screenshot changes to the second screenshot.
I have tried incognito mode with the same results.


Trying the suggested ephemeral mode made no difference.
The error message takes approximatley 20 minutes to appear.
Has anybody else experienced this today?
Thanks

From the discussions in comments, it seems the issue has been resolved. In case,If you are still facing this issue. Please report at Issue Tracker.
